# AWS: Where do I see a list of origin access identities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

When I created a CloudFront distribution, an **origin access identity** was created, so that CloudFront can use it to access the S3 bucket. But where do I see it? I went through IAM links and I can't find a list of such access identities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An Origin Access Identity is not an IAM user or role. It's possible to view Origin Access Identities in the following ways:

1. Web console: Click on Origin Access Identity on the panel located on
   the left of your Cloudfront dashboard

[image]

2. CLI tool: Run the following command

   *aws cloudfront list-cloud-front-origin-access-identities --output json*

Answer (score 4):

You can create and edit an **Origin Access Identity** from the CloudFront console.

The format for specifying the origin access identity in a Principal statement is:

```
"Principal": {"CanonicalUser": "Amazon S3 Canonical User ID"}
```

Or

```
"Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity <ORIGIN_ACCESS_IDENTITY_ID>"}
```

For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1476619022955",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity D3KJWPO38AQ6YV"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::static.example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

See [Using an Origin Access Identity to Restrict Access to Your Amazon S3 Content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).

Answer (score 3):

When you add Origin Access Identity, it will add a policy to S3 bucket. Check the following example policy found in [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-6) documentation.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Id":"PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Sid":" Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be"},
       "Action":"s3:GetObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashan! So this so called "**origin access identity**" is not a user or role, just a policy? That is what confused me.

Comment: Yes. Its confusing. I haven't look into whether its possible using IAM assume role with this policy having trust relationship with CloudFront(Which is the normal way of providing permission in AWS). But couldn't find any documentations as such, so assuming its not possible.